# Lubuntu 14.04.03 Intermitted boot issues

Tags: boot, lubuntu

Good day

Hope there is someone that can help or point me into the right direction. I am currently doing testing for a client that is running Lubuntu 14.04.03 on the following configuration: J1900 2.0Ghz CPU, 4GB DDR3 SO-DIMM RAM, 64GB SSD and the OS that I am testing is customized in some way to just auto install. Now I am no Linux specialist and have no experience with this OS at all and the client is using this as a Point of Sale terminal.

So I do the installation from a USB Flash Drive and it comes up with the Message to Restart Now and I just tap on the button and it attempts to restart. In many cases, the unit refuses to reboot and have to power it down and switch it back on to boot up, This is something that the client doesn't want to happen. Then to test a Auto Reboot that will happen during night time after updates I enter the following command:sleep 5000; sudo shutdown -r now to enable the terminal to auto reboot after the 5000 second time limit. That also fails at times. But I also have to add that I put the screen to sleep after 10min so the screen goes blank and leave it like that and do not interrupt the process. On very few occasions I've had success that the machine will reboot successfully but most of the time the unit just fails.

I also have to add that the above procedure works fine on the 1037U chipset and did not have any issues.

I also had the Motherboard manufacturer to look at the BIOS to see if there could be a problem in the BIOS and they provided me with an update and it worked for a while but I am now back at square one and need some professional help in this matter. Could this be a Lubuntu issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu SE.  Feel free to take the tour at https://askubuntu.com/Tour that will help you get the most from this site.  I trust someone will be able to give you some guidance on this question.  I haven't seen Lubuntu cause anything like this, especially from a fresh install.  I trust you are following the screen prompt to remove the install drive as it reboots - you might want to add that step to your post here.  The more information you supply in your question, the better the answers it will attract.

Comment: Unlike Ubuntu 14.04, Lubuntu 14.04 is no longer supported.